# Fiddler POST Invalid Header Name

Tags: wcf, rest, fiddler

I am sending a POST request to a WCF Web service using fiddler, and the service responds with HTTP 400: The request has an invalid header name.
The post request looks like this:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:49392
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
{  "clientFirstName" : "John"}
```

My endpoint is defined as follows:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke
       (Method = "POST",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
       UriTemplate = "MakeReservation")]
 String MakeReservation(Stream reservationStream);
```

**MORE**

First of all, the JSON was in the wrong pane. I moved it to the Request Body pane.

I changed the prototype of the function to take a String instead of Stream as the input parameter.  The service now accepts my call and returns 200, but in the debugger I see that the input parameter String is null. When I change it back to Stream, I get 400 again.

**YET MORE**

Enable tracing gives me at trace file with the following message:

```
Incoming message for operation 'MakeReservation' (contract 'ITalLimoService' with namespace 
'http://tempuri.org/') contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Json'. The expected body 
format value is 'Raw'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the 
binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.
```

As noted int the WebInvoke definitiuon, both the RequestFormat and ResponseFormat are set  to WebMessageFormate.Json.  Why is IIS complaining about this?

Comment: The data in your first block is malformed; you are showing JSON text in the headers, and you have a `Content-Length: 0` when you are clearly sending content. Please update your question so we can see exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why this works, but for some reason removing the following line from the fiddler Composer did the trick:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

And that is that. I would give points for an explanation.

Comment: The error message seems to explain exactly the issue: `This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the 
binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.`

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old. But very strange, when I removed the header "application/json" it worked.

Has it got to do with server setup?

Answer (score -1):

The request could not be understood by the server due to deformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.If request to your server with data that is in the correct format, but its bad data. eg: a Posted String value to an API endpoint that expected a String value; but, the value of the string contained data that was something else.

The syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions. For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains syntactically correct but semantically wrong XML instructions.